# What does the interrupt code for packet processing in the TCP/IP?

Tags: linux, sockets, driver, linux-device-driver, interrupt

I use TCP/IP over Ethernet 10 Gbit/s on Linux x86_64.

But what happen when interrupt occured in one of CPU-Core?

Is it true, that happens:

- code of interrupt calculates checksum of IP-packet
- code of interrupt copies data from kernel-space buffer to the required socket-buffer
- code of interrupt copies data from the buffer on Ethernet-card to the buffer in kernel-space (or it occurs before an interrupt is generated, by using DMA-controller on Ethernet and is this initiated by Ethernet-card?)

Comment: You are talking about a Kernel Driver right? I can't understand the connection between 'using BSD socket() and using epoll() for demultiplexing' and question about how driver actually works. Or your question about epoll facility in general? Looks like you have merge 3 diffrent things in your question.

Comment: @Maquefel I removed clarification about BSD Sockets and epoll. Yes, I am about Kernel Driver, and what happen in interrupt code.

Comment: Hardware kernel driver or the actual protocols ?

Comment: @Maquefel Interested in both, if they executed during interrupt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a mix of hardware, protocol stack and user-space.

> code of interrupt calculates checksum of IP-packet

this part is protocols - i think somewhere here net/ipv4/ip_input.c

> code of interrupt copies data from kernel-space buffer to the required socket-buffer

mix of proto and user space for example here net/ipv4/tcp_input.c

> code of interrupt copies data from the buffer on Ethernet-card to the buffer in kernel-space (or it occurs before an interrupt is generated, by using DMA-controller on Ethernet and is this initiated by Ethernet-card?)

this is hardware for example drivers/net/8139cp.c

Next - i think you are misunderstanding the "interrupt" term - there are hardware interrupts and software interrupts.
The only hardware interrupt here are rx/tx interrupts from Ethernet controller.

Not a full answer to your question:

First of all it is possible to divide networking into two parts the actual protocols (net/ipv4 directory) 
and part which implements various network hardware (drivers/net).

Not all hardware drivers implement interrupt driven technique some drivers for high-bandwidth adapter use poll technique (NAPI interface - which i shortly describe).

1. Packets are first received by the card. When interface receives "data arrived interrupt", it disables interrupt and tells kernel to start polling the interface.
2. Then when packet is available the interrupt handler leaves it in the interface and a method netif_rx_schedule is called. Which causes interface driver poll method to be called in some future.
3. then it goes to network layer and finally (but not so short as i described) goes to user space, and user is notified about data available for read event, which i can't call an interrupt.

I recommend you reading the following article:

Linux Networking Kernel (http://www.ecsl.cs.sunysb.edu/elibrary/linux/network/LinuxKernel.pdf)

Comment: Thank you! Can you say please, at least how many times data is copied and how many times is read (for example, for checksum) during hardware interrupt? (when I uses TCP over Ethernet with sockets, if it is important)

Comment: NAPI ~ 1 interrupt (as i said on arrival it is disabled and poll mode is set), if not NAPI interrupt can occur as many times as data arrived, transmited and data is read exactly one time everywhere. Check sum is not calculated during hardware interrupt (and it can be not a ip layer checksum at all),  - it's protocol layer responsibility and is caclulated here http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/ip_input.c#L376 for exaple for ip layer.

Comment: Thank you very much! I.e. for NAPI, in 1 hardware interrupt the data is copied only 1 time. But, can you clarify, when interrupt occured, where data of the ethernet-frame at this time: in the hardware buffer on Ethernet-card, or already in the CPU-RAM buffer?

Comment: Nope, the scheme is following - sleeping until interrupt, interrupt, disable interrupt - read all data (data is polled i.e. asking - do you have something?), when data all readed enable interrupt, sleeping until interrupt again. When hardware interrupt is occurred all data is in device. And a general rule is read all data from the device as soon as possible.

Comment: I.e. data copies from Ethernet-device to the CPU-RAM buffer by using Ethernet-DMA-controller. When interrupt occur and poll success, then the interrupt handler initiate copying by using this DMA-controller and poll success-flag of finishing this operation, isn't it? But in this case we are spending CPU-clocks to waiting data copies by DMA-controller, why it has not copied before interrupt has occur? (Ethernet-DMA-controller could be initiated by Ethernet-card directly)

Comment: First of all we can't discuss it in general, it depends on the specific card and driver-specific. If we copy data before interrupt occurs (which is possible only if interrupt is disabled) - then for what do we need interrupts at all - we can constant poll a device? Second - in the world there are many not PCI Ethernet controller's.  You are trying to trying to cover the whole world in the form of a small issue, cause now you asking about a specific PCIe implementation of Ethernet card :), which require studying PCI bus.

Answer (score 2):

I think this it the way of working of DMA (bus mastering) capable network interfaces with NAPI driver:

When packet(s) arrive, Socket Buffers are already allocated and mapped to DMA memory buffer, and DMA is armed.

1. Packet is transferred from NIC to Socket Buffer through DMA
2. NIC raises hardware interrupt when DMA transfer is done.
3. Hardware interrupt handler schedules packet receiving software interrupt (SOFTIRQ)
4. SOFTIRQ calls NAPI poll() for further processing.
5. NAPI poll() process packets in DMA buffer queue and and passes them to upper layers as `sk_buff` and initializes new DMA buffers. if all packets (quota) are processed, IRQ is enabled and NAPI is told to stop polling.